# Error message when try to install module ''Record does not exist or has been deleted'' on Odoo 12.0 community

Tags: python, odoo-12

I have a problem when trying to instal or update a module from apps list, also, I can't update apps list,

the error message is  : "Record does not exist or has been deleted"

[image]

And this is the console error :

[image: screenshot]

Please Help.

Comment: there is a field that does not exist, maybe you have to create a field then you deleted or a model and then you deleted

Comment: Hi thank you for your message, is there a way to find out which module or field that causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

which module did you try to update ?
Check the depends of this module

Comment: Hi thank you for your message, Actually I have this issue on all modules, so, I can't update or install any module.

Comment: did you restore this database or it's a new one ?

Comment: No, it is new one, also, I can not backup the database (odoo server error)

Comment: Can you share the sceenshot of log lines before the error above